# How do I address a element of a list separated by commas?

Tags: python, list

So I've got a wordlist like this:

```
['james,1', 'deb,10', 'bad,1']
```

So each element of the list contains a word and a number, in which I need to eventually find the number of appearances of that word from a separate text and then add the number, but right now what I don't know is how I can address the first and second "parts" separated by commas of each element so that I can later implement in my code to find the appearances of the words. for example, how would I be able to address the word "amazed"? If the word "james" were by itself in the second element, I know I can just do wordlist[1] but how would it work in this case? Do I have to split this list into a nested list or something? If so, how?

Comment: Use `split(',')` to split the string into two parts.

Comment: Why did you do it like this in the first place? Why not a list of tuples, `[('alone', 1), ('amazed', 10), ...]`?

Comment: how would i go about turning that into a tuple list?

Comment: Do it in the code that creates the list in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need nested tuple pairs of the strings:

```
ml = ['alone,1', 'amazed,10', 'bad,1', 'best,10', 'better,10', 'excellent,10', 'excite,10', 'good,7', 'great,7', 'happy,10', 'hard,5', 'hardest,4', 'hate,1', 'like,7', 'love,10', 'loves,10', 'need,1', 'regret,1', 'sad,1', 'sorry,1', 'thank,5', 'tired,1', 'worst,1']
nums = [(x.split(",")[0],int(x.split(",")[1])) for x in ml]
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
('alone', 1), ('amazed', 10), ('bad', 1), ('best', 10), ('better', 10), ('excellent', 10), ('excite', 10), ('good', 7), ('great', 7), ('happy', 10), ('hard', 5), ('hardest', 4), ('hate', 1), ('like', 7), ('love', 10), ('loves', 10), ('need', 1), ('regret', 1), ('sad', 1), ('sorry', 1), ('thank', 5), ('tired', 1), ('worst', 1)]
```

Even better get a dictionary after the earilier code:

```
nums = dict(nums)
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
{'alone': 1, 'amazed': 10, 'bad': 1, 'best': 10, 'better': 10, 'excellent': 10, 'excite': 10, 'good': 7, 'great': 7, 'happy': 10, 'hard': 5, 'hardest': 4, 'hate': 1, 'like': 7, 'love': 10, 'loves': 10, 'need': 1, 'regret': 1, 'sad': 1, 'sorry': 1, 'thank': 5, 'tired': 1, 'worst': 1}
```

Use a list comprehension to get only the integer part:

```
ml = ['alone,1', 'amazed,10', 'bad,1', 'best,10', 'better,10', 'excellent,10', 'excite,10', 'good,7', 'great,7', 'happy,10', 'hard,5', 'hardest,4', 'hate,1', 'like,7', 'love,10', 'loves,10', 'need,1', 'regret,1', 'sad,1', 'sorry,1', 'thank,5', 'tired,1', 'worst,1']
nums = [int(x.split(",")[1]) for x in ml]
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
[1, 10, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 7, 7, 10, 5, 4, 1, 7, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution to your problem

```
def get_index_of_word(word:str, wordlist:list):
    for entry in wordlist:
        splitted_list = entry.split(",")
        entry_word = splitted_list[0]
        if word == entry_word:
            return int(splitted_list[1])
    return None
```

2. What you really need to do: Format the data structure to tuple or dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict for this kinda process

```
a=['alone,1', 'amazed,10', 'bad,1', 'best,10', 'better,10', 'excellent,10', 'excite,10', 'good,7', 'great,7', 'happy,10', 'hard,5', 'hardest,4', 'hate,1', 'like,7', 'love,10', 'loves,10', 'need,1', 'regret,1', 'sad,1', 'sorry,1', 'thank,5', 'tired,1', 'worst,1']

d={}

for i in a:
    d[i.split(',')[0]]=int(i.split(',')[1])

print(d["happy"])
```